# AWS S3 Ember CLI Static Hosting Routing Issue Throwing 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3, ember-cli

I am trying to deploy my Ember app to AWS. I have taken the following [steps found here.](http://kerrygallagher.co.uk/deploying-an-ember-cli-application-to-amazon-s3/) The app loads but immediately throws a 404 once the URL/route changes since those files do not exist on the S3 bucket. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Change your location from history to hash.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html